# Randomly choosing a row

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I have table s1, which has 3 rows. How can I RANDOMLY pick a row from s1 and INSERT its corresponding value into d1.

I don't want a hard coded solution. Can ROWNUM() be used then dbms_random? Let's say I want 10 rows in d1.

An example would be appreciated.

```
Create table s1(
val NUMBER(4)
);

 INSERT into s1
(val) VALUES (30);

 INSERT into s1
 (val) VALUES (40);

 INSERT into s1
 (val) VALUES (50);

Create table d1(
val NUMBER(4)
 );
```

Comment: How big is your table S1?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by a random value and select one row:

```
insert into d1 (val)
    select val
    from (select s1.*
          from s1
          order by dbms_random.value
         ) s1
    where rownum = 1;
```

In Oracle 12C+, you don't need the subquery:

```
insert into d1 (val)
    select val
    from s1
    order by dbms_random.value
    fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  This assumes that you really mean *random* and not arbitrary.  A random row means that any row in the table has an equal chance of being chosen in any given invocation of the query.

Comment: Thanks,  can this be wrapped into a cte and the value referenced by a variable? I need to get a value from a table and include it with other variables

Comment: @Beefstu . . . That is not the question you asked here.  This question is about inserting the rows into another table.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

In case of huge tables standard way with sorting by dbms_random.value is not effective because you need to scan whole table and dbms_random.value is pretty slow function and requires context switches. For such cases, there are 2 well-known methods:

1. Use `sample` clause:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6

for example:

```sql
select *
from s1 sample block(1)
order by dbms_random.value
fetch first 1 rows only
```

ie get 1% of all blocks, then sort them randomly and return just 1 row.

2. if you have an index/primary key on the column with normal distribution, you can get min and max values, get random value in this range and get first row with a value greater or equal than that randomly generated value.

Example:

```sql
--big table with 1 mln rows with primary key on ID with normal distribution:
Create table s1(id primary key,padding) as 
   select level, rpad('x',100,'x')
   from dual 
   connect by level<=1e6;

select *
from s1 
where id>=(select 
              dbms_random.value(
                 (select min(id) from s1),
                 (select max(id) from s1) 
              )
           from dual)
order by id
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

**Update**

and 3rd variant: get random table block, generate rowid and get row from the table by this rowid:

```sql
select * 
from s1
where rowid = (
   select
      DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_CREATE (
         1, 
         objd,
         file#,
         block#,
         1) 
   from    
      (
      select/*+ rule */ file#,block#,objd
      from v$bh b
      where b.objd in (select o.data_object_id from user_objects o where object_name='S1' /* table_name */)
      order by dbms_random.value
      fetch first 1 rows only
      )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: @Beefstu you're welcome! :) you can upvote liked answers and mark beet-suited answer as a  correct