# Using the sample function in a complex query in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to select a random sample of the rows returned by my query. I have read the answer [How to get records randomly from the oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868409/how-to-get-records-randomly-from-the-oracle-database) but I cannot get the dbms_random.random to work, so I tried with the sample function.

But I am getting an error when I request a sample of my values. A reproducible example would be:
**The example queries provided are just for reproducability, they have nothing to do with my actual usecase (as in I do not want to select 7 rows or something similar)**

```
select * from (select 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 from dual) sample(0.1)
-- doesn't work
select * from (select 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 from dual)t sample(0.1)
-- doesn't work either
```

What am I doing wrong here? My goal is to select a random sample of the results of the subquery but I do not have privileges to use `dbms_random.value`.

Comment: Sample clause is for real tables only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866089/randomly-choosing-a-row/62866447#62866447

Comment: Are you sure that you have not privileges on `dbms_random.value`? What does return `select dbms_random.value() v from dual` ?

Comment: Also you can use `((1+mod(ora_hash(sys_guid()),1000))/1000)` instead of dbms_random.value(). Example: `select ((1+mod(ora_hash(sys_guid()),1000))/1000) rand from dual;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic function VALUE from DBMS_RANDOM gets a random number, greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1, with 38 digits to the right of the decimal (38-digit precision).

Alternatively, when specify low and high limits, it retrieves a random number between. In your case, you can get a random integer value between 1 and 7 using

```
select round(dbms_random.value(1,7),0) from dual ;
```

You can get those values even from your table

```
select round(dbms_random.value(a.min_value,a.max_value),0) from my_table a ;
```

As you did not explain what exactly you want to select from your table, I can just provide you with a generic answer.

Comment: My problem with dbms_random.value is that when I try to use it I get : "ORA-0094: DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE invalid identifier"

Comment: apparently you don't have privileges over DBMS_RANDOM. Your DBA should be granting EXECUTE privilege to your user.

Comment: Yeah this would take some time to change that's why I am trying to work around it.

Comment: Turns out I managed to get the rights so I guess this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support sampling of derived tables or views that are not key-preserving ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Oracle-Support-for-Optional-Features-of-SQLFoundation2011.html#GUID-3BA98AEC-FAAD-4F21-A6AD-F696B5D36D56)).

Also, note that if you want to create 1 row for each of the first 7 integers in Oracle:

```
select level
from dual
connect by level <= 7
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I make my query key-preserving? I am joining two tables in it, I tried selecting the keys of the tables but this did not work either.

Comment: @User2321 You could use a temporary table: `create table x as ...` then select from x using `sample` and drop x